# Getting error on dots, () and new

Tags: java, android, ant

I want to compile a modified Version of a GCM Server.

But i am getting errors which i cant explain.

```
/*
 * Copyright 2012 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 * use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 * the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.google.android.gcm.demo.server;

import com.google.android.gcm.server.Constants;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.MulticastResult;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet that adds a new message to all registered devices.
 * <p>
 * This servlet is used just by the browser (i.e., not device).
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SendAllMessagesServlet extends BaseServlet {

  private static final int MULTICAST_SIZE = 1000;

  private Sender sender;

  private static final Executor threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

  @Override
  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    sender = newSender(config);
  }

  /**
   * Creates the {@link Sender} based on the servlet settings.
   */
  protected Sender newSender(ServletConfig config) {
    String key = (String) config.getServletContext()
        .getAttribute(ApiKeyInitializer.ATTRIBUTE_ACCESS_KEY);
    return new Sender(key);
  }

  /**
   * Processes the request to add a new message.
   */
  @Override
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    List<String> devices = Datastore.getDevices();
    String status;
    if (devices.isEmpty()) {
      status = "Message ignored as there is no device registered!";
    } else {
      // NOTE: check below is for demonstration purposes; a real application
      // could always send a multicast, even for just one recipient
      if (devices.size() == 1) {
        // send a single message using plain post
        String registrationId = devices.get(0);
        Message message = new Message.Builder();
//MY LANES
        message.setData("echo", req.getAttribute("message").toString());
        message.build();
//END
        Result result = sender.send(message, registrationId, 5);
        status = "Sent message to one device: " + result;
      } else {
        // send a multicast message using JSON
        // must split in chunks of 1000 devices (GCM limit)
        int total = devices.size();
        List<String> partialDevices = new ArrayList<String>(total);
        int counter = 0;
        int tasks = 0;
        for (String device : devices) {
          counter++;
          partialDevices.add(device);
          int partialSize = partialDevices.size();
          if (partialSize == MULTICAST_SIZE || counter == total) {

            msg = req.getAttribute("message");
            asyncSend(partialDevices);
            partialDevices.clear();
            tasks++;
          }
        }
        status = "Asynchronously sending " + tasks + " multicast messages to " +
            total + " devices";
      }
    }
    req.setAttribute(HomeServlet.ATTRIBUTE_STATUS, status.toString());
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home").forward(req, resp);
  }

  public String msg = "";

  private void asyncSend(List<String> partialDevices) {
    // make a copy
    final List<String> devices = new ArrayList<String>(partialDevices);
    threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {

      public void run() {
        Message message = new Message.Builder();
//MY LANES
         message.setData("echo", msg);
         message.build();
//END
        MulticastResult multicastResult;
        try {
          multicastResult = sender.send(message, devices, 5);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error posting messages", e);
          return;
        }
        List<Result> results = multicastResult.getResults();
        // analyze the results
        for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
          String regId = devices.get(i);
          Result result = results.get(i);
          String messageId = result.getMessageId();
          if (messageId != null) {
            logger.fine("Succesfully sent message to device: " + regId +
                "; messageId = " + messageId);
            String canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalRegistrationId();
            if (canonicalRegId != null) {
              // same device has more than on registration id: update it
              logger.info("canonicalRegId " + canonicalRegId);
              Datastore.updateRegistration(regId, canonicalRegId);
            }
          } else {
            String error = result.getErrorCodeName();
            if (error.equals(Constants.ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED)) {
              // application has been removed from device - unregister it
              logger.info("Unregistered device: " + regId);
              Datastore.unregister(regId);
            } else {
              logger.severe("Error sending message to " + regId + ": " + error);
            }
          }
        }
      }});
  }

}
```

and the response of the Compiler is here:

```
C:\Users\Sebastian Reuther\android-sdks\extras\google\gcm\samples\gcm-demo-serve
r>"C:\Users\Sebastian Reuther\android-sdks\extras\google\gcm\samples\apache-ant-
1.8.4\bin\ant" war
Buildfile: C:\Users\Sebastian Reuther\android-sdks\extras\google\gcm\samples\gcm
-demo-server\build.xml

init:

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Sebastian Reuther\android-sdks\e
xtras\google\gcm\samples\gcm-demo-server\build\classes
    [javac]
    [javac]           WARNING
    [javac]
    [javac] The -source switch defaults to 1.7 in JDK 1.7.
    [javac] If you specify -target 1.5 you now must also specify -source 1.5.
    [javac] Ant will implicitly add -source 1.5 for you.  Please change your bui
ld file.
    [javac] warning: java\io\IOException.class(java\io:IOException.class): major
 version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compil
er.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\util\ArrayList.class(java\util:ArrayList.class): major
 version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compil
er.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\util\List.class(java\util:List.class): major version 5
1 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\util\concurrent\Executor.class(java\util\concurrent:Ex
ecutor.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supp
orted by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\util\concurrent\Executors.class(java\util\concurrent:E
xecutors.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version su
pported by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\util\logging\Level.class(java\util\logging:Level.class
): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by thi
s compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\io\Serializable.class(java\io:Serializable.class): maj
or version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this comp
iler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\Object.class(java\lang:Object.class): major versi
on 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\SuppressWarnings.class(java\lang:SuppressWarnings
.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\String.class(java\lang:String.class): major versi
on 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\annotation\Target.class(java\lang\annotation:Targ
et.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supporte
d by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\annotation\ElementType.class(java\lang\annotation
:ElementType.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major versio
n supported by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\annotation\Retention.class(java\lang\annotation:R
etention.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version su
pported by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\annotation\RetentionPolicy.class(java\lang\annota
tion:RetentionPolicy.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest majo
r version supported by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\annotation\Annotation.class(java\lang\annotation:
Annotation.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version
supported by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\Override.class(java\lang:Override.class): major v
ersion 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler
.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\Error.class(java\lang:Error.class): major version
 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\Exception.class(java\lang:Exception.class): major
 version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compil
er.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\Throwable.class(java\lang:Throwable.class): major
 version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compil
er.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\RuntimeException.class(java\lang:RuntimeException
.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported
by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\util\concurrent\ExecutorService.class(java\util\concur
rent:ExecutorService.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest majo
r version supported by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\util\Collection.class(java\util:Collection.class): maj
or version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this comp
iler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\Iterable.class(java\lang:Iterable.class): major v
ersion 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler
.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] C:\Users\Sebastian Reuther\android-sdks\extras\google\gcm\samples\gc
m-demo-server\src\com\google\android\gcm\demo\server\SendAllMessagesServlet.java
:81: incompatible types
    [javac] found   : com.google.android.gcm.server.Message.Builder
    [javac] required: com.google.android.gcm.server.Message
    [javac]         Message message = new Message.Builder();
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] C:\Users\Sebastian Reuther\android-sdks\extras\google\gcm\samples\gc
m-demo-server\src\com\google\android\gcm\demo\server\SendAllMessagesServlet.java
:82: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method setData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    [javac] location: class com.google.android.gcm.server.Message
    [javac]         message.setData("echo", req.getAttribute("message").toString
());
    [javac]                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\Sebastian Reuther\android-sdks\extras\google\gcm\samples\gc
m-demo-server\src\com\google\android\gcm\demo\server\SendAllMessagesServlet.java
:83: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method build()
    [javac] location: class com.google.android.gcm.server.Message
    [javac]         message.build();
    [javac]                ^
    [javac] warning: java\lang\Comparable.class(java\lang:Comparable.class): maj
or version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this comp
iler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\lang\CharSequence.class(java\lang:CharSequence.class):
 major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this
compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\util\AbstractList.class(java\util:AbstractList.class):
 major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this
compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\util\AbstractCollection.class(java\util:AbstractCollec
tion.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version suppor
ted by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] C:\Users\Sebastian Reuther\android-sdks\extras\google\gcm\samples\gc
m-demo-server\src\com\google\android\gcm\demo\server\SendAllMessagesServlet.java
:99: incompatible types
    [javac] found   : java.lang.Object
    [javac] required: java.lang.String
    [javac]             msg = req.getAttribute("message");
    [javac]                                   ^
    [javac] warning: java\lang\Runnable.class(java\lang:Runnable.class): major v
ersion 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler
.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] C:\Users\Sebastian Reuther\android-sdks\extras\google\gcm\samples\gc
m-demo-server\src\com\google\android\gcm\demo\server\SendAllMessagesServlet.java
:121: incompatible types
    [javac] found   : com.google.android.gcm.server.Message.Builder
    [javac] required: com.google.android.gcm.server.Message
    [javac]         Message message = new Message.Builder();
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] C:\Users\Sebastian Reuther\android-sdks\extras\google\gcm\samples\gc
m-demo-server\src\com\google\android\gcm\demo\server\SendAllMessagesServlet.java
:122: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method setData(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    [javac] location: class com.google.android.gcm.server.Message
    [javac]          message.setData("echo", msg);
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] C:\Users\Sebastian Reuther\android-sdks\extras\google\gcm\samples\gc
m-demo-server\src\com\google\android\gcm\demo\server\SendAllMessagesServlet.java
:123: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method build()
    [javac] location: class com.google.android.gcm.server.Message
    [javac]          message.build();
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] warning: java\util\logging\Logger.class(java\util\logging:Logger.cla
ss): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by t
his compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] warning: java\util\logging\LogRecord.class(java\util\logging:LogReco
rd.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supporte
d by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] 7 errors
    [javac] 30 warnings

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Sebastian Reuther\android-sdks\extras\google\gcm\samples\gcm-demo-serve
r\build.xml:52: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Any Idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a version conflict between the libs/JDK you use, and the ones your libs are compiled with.

Comment: Do you know how to Update the Compiler? I just downloadeded it from the Official Homepage.. It's Apache Ant 1.8.4 P.S.: Before i added my Lines all worked fine.

Comment: Try setting the target-version to 1.5 in the `javac`-task. `<javac source="1.7" target="1.5">`.

Comment: Then i get: compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Sebastian Reuther\android-sdks\e
xtras\google\gcm\samples\gcm-demo-server\build\classes
    [javac] javac: invalid source release: 1.7
    [javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
    [javac] use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: "1.7" was only a guess. If you are using 1.6, than use this. Find out typing `java -version` on your commandline.

Comment: java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)

Seems, that i have 1.7...